# LC_COLLATE (sort-order) differences between Linux and macOS

Tags: macos, sorting, unix, encoding, locale

I have an issue sorting text with accented letters with the `sort` command on macOS.

Here is my locale setup :

```
LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="fr_FR.UTF-8"
```

Here is a simple text file with the associated `hexdump -C` :

```
î
a
z
```

Hexdump:

```
00000000  c3 ae 0a 61 0a 7a 0a 0a
```

Here is what I get when I use the `sort` command on macOS :

```
a
z
î
```

Which is the right order. However, with the same locale settings, I get the right result on Ubuntu :

```
a
î
z
```

How could I set up my macOS installation so that it works the same way as Ubuntu ?